# How to deal with checking for valid state in every method call

Tags: f#

I have encountered some code that looks like this.

```
member this.Send (data:array<byte>) =
    if tcpClient.Connected then
        // Send something.

member this.Open () =
    if not tcpClient.Connected then
        // Connect.
```

It's a potential bug hive with constantly checking to see if the `TcpClient` is connected before performing an operation on it.

A similar problem would be to check whether or not something is `null` before performing an operation on that something.

What is the general approach to dealing with this?
I was thinking along the lines of a monad that abstracts this boring checking away.

**EDIT:**
Potentially I can write many methods that each will have to check if we are connected.

```
member this.SendName name =
    if tcpClient.Connected then
        // Send name

member this.ThrottleConnection percent =
    if tcpClient.Connected then
        // Throttle

member this.SendAsTest text =
    if tcpClient.Connected then
        // Send as text.
```

Comment: `let whenOpen action = if tcpClient.Connected then action ()` => `member this.Send data = whenOpen (fun () -> ...)` - but please note that `.Connected` on a socket will not give the current status anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it depends on whether you want to do the check inside the wrapper class or outside of it.  Doing the check inside the class, I don't see how a computation expression is really relevant; you're not binding operations.

A workflow expression would only be useful if you're doing the check outside the wrapper class (i.e. from the calling function).  If you create a `connected` builder together, the resulting code would look like

```
connected {
  do! wrapper.Send(..)
  do! wrapper.Throttle(..)
  do! wrapper.SendAsTest(..)
}
```

However, that is really no simpler than

```
if wrapper.connected do
  wrapper.Send(..)
  wrapper.Throttle(..)
  wrapper.SendAsTest(..)
```

So, kind of, what's the point, right?

It'd make more sense if you had multiple `tcpClient` wrapper objects and needed them all to be connected within your workflow.  That's more what the "monadic" approach is for.

```
connected {
  do! wrapper1.Send(..)
  do! wrapper2.Throttle(..)
  do! wrapper3.SendAsText(..)
}
```

However, specific to your example of doing the checks inside the wrapper class, like I said earlier, monads would not be applicable.  One neat approach to that specific problem would be to try mimicking some preconditions like the following link http://laurent.le-brun.eu/site/index.php/2008/03/26/32-design-by-contract-with-fsharp.  I don't know if it's much more intuitive than the `if` statements, but if you're looking for an fsharp-y way of doing things interestingly, that's the best I can come up with.

Ultimately your existing code is about as compact as it gets.  Presumably not *all* of your functions would start with the same `if` statement, so there's nothing unnecessarily repetitive there.

Comment: Well, my problem with the code is not repeated calls to `Send()`, but rather that every "active" operation on the `TcpClient` i write, I will have to check to see whether or not I am connected. I have edited my question to state this more clearly.

Comment: @lejon Understood, the answer here still holds, just replace the `Send` methods above with various methods.

Comment: you don't have to check this for everything (if we are talking sockets) - indeed `Connected` only makes sense after a read/send